# How to avoid dirty data caused by duplicate operation on different devices in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, action-filter

Let's say we have two simple tables:

[image]

The boolean column `is_paid` of the `order` table is used to mark whether the order is paid. Whenever an order is paid, we insert a record into the `log` table. An order could be paid by running the  `order/pay` action:

```
/**
 * Controller
 */
class OrderController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionPay($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->pay();
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'You have paid the order.');

        return $this->goHome();
    }
}


/**
 * Model
 */
class Order extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Pay an order
     */
    public function pay()
    {
        $this->is_paid = 1;

        // whenever the order is paid, log the payment
        $this->on(self::EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE, [$this, 'log'], "paid order # {$this->id}");

        if (!$this->save()) {
            throw new \yii\db\Exception('Failed');
        }
    }

    /**
     * After the order was paid, log the payment.
     */
    public function log($event)
    {
        $message = $event->data;

        $log = new Log(['message' => $message]);

        if (!log->save()) {
            throw new \yii\db\Exception('Failed');
        }
    }
}
```

## 1 Reproduce the problem

Suppose that there is an unpaid order in the `order` table, the end user first visited `order/index` on a PC, then he revisited `order/index` on a mobile phone. Now, the status of the order on both devices was unpaid.

The end user clicked the 'pay' button on PC to pay the order, after the operation, the `is_paid` value of the order was changed to `1`, and there was a new record in the `log` table. After a while, the user reopened the `order/index` page on the mobile phone, **as the page was no reloaded, the order's status was still UNPAID**, if the user clicks the 'pay' button, **there will be a duplicate log record**, dirty data occurs.

## 2 How to avoid

### 2.1 Solution A: Pre-Check in every action

Before executing `$model->pay()`, we could do a pre-check:

```
class OrderController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionPay($id)
    {
        $model->$this->findModel($id);

        // pre-check 
        if($model->is_paid) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('warning', 'This order has been paid.');
            return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
        }

        $model->pay();
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'You have paid the order.');

        return $this->goHome();
    }
}
```

One of the cons of solution A is that it makes the action less clean, What's more, such checks are frequent in many cases, writing similar code in every action is a verbose job.

### 2.2 Solution B: Action Filter

We could create an generic action filter called `StatusGuardFilter`:

```
namespace backend\behaviors;

use Yii;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;

class StatusGuardFilter extends \yii\base\ActionFilter
{
    public $modelClass;

    // find the specified AR record
    protected function findModel()
    {
        $modelClass = $this->modelClass;
        $keys = $modelClass::primaryKey();
        $values = [];
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            $values[] = Yii::$app->request->get($key);
        }
        $model = $modelClass::findOne(array_combine($keys, $values));

        if (isset($model)) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("Object not found.");
        }
    }

    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel();

        // check if $action is allowed, method detail is following
        $errorMsg = $model->getStatusGuardErrorMessage($action->id);

        if ($errorMsg) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('warning', $errorMsg);
            $action->controller->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}


/**
 * Model
 */
class Order extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Check whether an order could run $action
     *
     * @param string $action action name
     *
     * @return string|null if the action is forbidden, an error message will be returned, or null if the action is allowed.
     */
    public function getStatusGuardErrorMessage($action)
    {
        switch ($action) {
            case 'pay':
                if ($this->is_paid) {
                    return 'This order has been paid.';
                }
                break;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Based the aboved code, now we rewrite OrderController as following:

```
/**
 * Controller
 */

use backend\behaviors\StatusGuardFilter;

class OrderController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'guard' => [
                'only' => ['pay'],
                'class' => StatusGuardFilter::className(),
                'modelClass' => '\backend\models\Order',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionPay($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->pay();
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'You have paid the order.');

        return $this->goHome();
    }
}
```

#### 2.2.1 Pros and cons of solution B

Pros

The action code looks clean; The action filter is reusable, for similar cases, what we need to do is: config `behaviors()`, then fill logic code in `getStatusGuardErrorMessage()`. For example, when updating an order, we want to ensure that the order is unpaid and it is created by current user. We change codes in the following three classes:

1. add `update` action into the `guard` behavior:

   ```
   public function behaviors()
   {
       return [
           'guard' => [
               'only' => ['pay', 'update'],
               // ...
           ],
       ];
   }
   ```
2. fill check logic of update operation in Order class:

   ```
   public function getStatusGuardErrorMessage($action)
   {
       switch ($action) {
           // ...
           case 'update':
               if ($this->is_paid) {
                   return 'Only unpaid order updating is allowed.';
               }
               if ($this->created_by != Yii::$app->user->id) {
                   return 'Only order's owner can update the order';
               }
               break;
       }

       return null;
   }
   ```

Cons: Extra DB query

The first query is in `StatusGuardFilter`:

```
class StatusGuardFilter extends \yii\base\ActionFilter
{
    protected function findModel()
    {
        // first DB query: findOne()
        $model = $modelClass::findOne(array_combine($keys, $values));
    }
}
```

If an order is allowed to pay, a duplicate DB query is executed in `findModel()` of `OrderController`:

```
class OrderController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionPay($id)
    {
        // in findModel(), we execute Order::findOne() twice
        $this->findModel($id)->pay();
    }
}
```

It seems that `findOne()` could not be cached, so solution B generates an extra DB query cost.

## 3 Question

Solution A vs Solution B, Which is better? or is there another better way?

Comment: None of this will protect from race condition. You should read about [optimistic locks](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#optimistic-locks) and/or [mutex component](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-mutex-mutex).

Comment: It's turned out that I'm complicating a simple question, please refer to this answer on Yii offical forum: https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/how-to-avoid-dirty-data-caused-by-duplicate-operation-on-different-devices/123287/4?u=drodata